# Unable To Run Espresso Tests With Headless Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-espresso

I created the avd by doing the following:

```
./avdmanager create avd -c 100M -n test -d 9 -k 'system-images;android-26;google_apis_playstore;x86'
```

I get the following output after running `avdmanager list avd`

```
  Name: test
  Device: Nexus 5X (Google)
    Path: /home/me/.android/avd/test.avd
  Target: Google Play (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis_playstore/x86
  Sdcard: 100M
```

Then I booted up the emulator by running

```
emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-boot-anim -no-window -skip-adb-auth & adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 1; done; input keyevent 82'
```

Then finally I try to run the tests with

```
 ./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

However, the process hangs and I assume will do so indefinitely, but I will kill the process after 10 minutes. I am not even sure how to debug this let one resolve it so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Which process hangs? The test process? In that case you should know which gradle task hangs at least.

However, if it is the emulator process hanging (not finishing booting) then I was able to resolve that in headless environment with these extra params for kvm:

`-qemu -enable-kvm -snapshot`

Obviously, you need kvm set up and enabled. ([KVM installation for ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation))